# Removing a fraction in the denominator

Tags: fractions

What steps do I need to take to simplify $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$ to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$? Can you please explain the steps i need to take in this problem and explain generally how to remove fractions from the denominator.

Comment: There exists a sentence:" A term can be divided by a fraction by multiplying the term by the reciprocal of the fraction." Do you know it ?

Comment: @calculus no I'm sorry I don't know that sentence.

Comment: It means the same what Michael Dyrud has demonstrated in his answer. As you marked it with a checkmark it seems that you have understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that division is the same as multiplying something by its reciprocal. In this case, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=1\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}=\sqrt{2}$, as desired. In general, to divide by a fraction, just multiply by the reciprocal.